# if using jquery to append multiple fields they are not posted to array

Tags: php, jquery, html, arrays, forms

Basically, I have page, where is static html, code:

```
<input type="text" name="exp[][from]" />
<input type="text" name="exp[][to]" />
<input type="text" name="exp[][position]" />
<input type="text" name="exp[][name]" />
```

After this input fields there is button to add more fields, that runs this jQuery code:

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
    $('#addwork').click(function() {
        $(document.createElement('div')).html('<input type="text" name="exp[][from]" />\n<input type="text" name="exp[][to]" />\n<input type="text" name="exp[][position]"  />\n<input type="text" name="exp[][name]" />').appendTo('.cvs');
    });
});
```

Problem is that if I add some fields with jQuery they are not posted to array( tested with var_dump ), but static one is. I tested and added few more fields in static html and it worked well.

So basically, if i append input fields they are not posted to array, but static ones are.

Comment: Please make sure that the javascript generated fields are appended before closing the form tag. Only when the fields are inside the form tag, the data will be posted

Comment: Tested, they are before form closing tag

Comment: Can you show [a demo](http://jsfiddle.net/), and your HTML (not just the HTML of the non-working appended items)? Oh, and only 'successful' `input` elements are submitted. Do these elements receive a value before submission? Does adding a `value=""` cause it to work as you'd expect?

Comment: demo: http://jsfiddle.net/QTQw7/1/ .Yes, these elements will be filled before submit. Tryed to add value="", but nothing changed

Comment: Weird, on jsFiddle everything works, but on my side not.. what can cause problem?

Comment: Can you tell me what is "exp[][to]" and why you using same name in new input fields. How you post data because you do have same name of new added input fields.

Answer (score 0):

Well I tried with a sample code and I am able to get the values of the appended items using var_dump. So please check this code

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
   $(document).ready(function(){
    $('#addwork').click(function() {
        $(document.createElement('div')).html('<input type="text" name="exp[][from]" />\n<input type="text" name="exp[][to]" />\n<input type="text" name="exp[][position]"  />\n<input type="text" name="exp[][name]" />').appendTo('.cvs');
    });
});

</script>
</head>
<form method="post">
<input type="text" name="exp[][from]" />
<input type="text" name="exp[][to]" />
<input type="text" name="exp[][position]" />
<input type="text" name="exp[][name]" />
<div class="cvs"></div>
<input type="submit" value="btn" name="btn"/>

<input type="button" value="add" id="addwork"/>
</form>
</html>
```

Comment: Yes, i just chechked and on jsFiddle works, but not on my localhost.. weird.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
                    $('#addwork').click(function() {
                        $('.cvs').append(
                                '<div>'+
                                    '<input type="text" name="exp[][from]" /><br>'+
                                    '<input type="text" name="exp[][to]" /><br>'+
                                    '<input type="text" name="exp[][position]"  /><br>'+
                                    '<input type="text" name="exp[][name]" />'+
                                '</div>');
                        });
                });
```

Answer (score 0):

make the format of the name attribute
exp[INTEGER][info]
this way you could "group" the form data but could result to big arrays